# Linking logout button in html to logout php

Tags: php

Does anyone know why my logout button isn't working? I have created a button in my HTML which looks like this:

```
<button  href="logout.php">Logout </button>
```

And then I have a PHP file called logout.php which looks like this:

```
 <?php
session_start();

if(session_destroy()) {
  header("Location: index.html");
}
?>
```

I don't know how to connect the two. If anyone could help me that would be great.

Comment: What happens? One should end up in the index.html

Comment: Last I knew, `<button>` doesn't use `href`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the PHP file using the bellow code.

As far as I know you can call an href directly from a button. Either you should use an anchor tag or a form to submit to particular a link.
[Here is the thread related to your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

```
<a href="your link..." class="btn btn-success">Logout</a>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! :) Will mark it correct when the 10 minutes has past

Answer (score -1):

It can not work on old php version.
What is your PHP version?
Or you may try session_unset() instead of session_destroy().

Answer (score -1):

There is anchor tag to redirect a page . But you want to use button then it can achieve by using javascript

```
  <button onclick="window.location.href='logout.php'">Logout</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
 <button  href="logout.php">Logout </button>
```

To

```
 <button><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></button>
```